# Why is this CATransition not working?

Tags: iphone, ios, core-animation

I'm trying to transition the text of a `UILabel`:

```
CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
animation.duration = 4;
animation.type = kCATransitionReveal;
animation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear];
[label.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:nil];

label.text = resultDateStr;
```

This works just fine. But when I set it to `kCATransitionFade`, it stops working. Tested on iOS 4.3 and 5.0 Any idea?

Comment: What happens? I just tested this on 4.3 and 5.1 simulators as well as 4.2.1 and 5.1 devices, and it works fine with `kCATransitionFade`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
[CATransaction begin];
CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
animation.type = kCATransitionFade;
animation.duration = 3.50;

[self.view addSubview:mySecondUIView]

[[self.view layer] addAnimation:animation forKey:@"Fade"];
[CATransaction commit];
```

Answer (score 0):

Verify that you perform this task on the main thread.